# SQLiteException: unrecognized token

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have create a SQLite Database inside my app. I am trying to show the content in TextView(android), but I have any problem with that.

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE "1_BASICA_1500" ("INDICACIONES" TEXT, "LUNES" TEXT, "MARTES" TEXT,
"MIERCOLES" TEXT, "JUEVES" TEXT, "VIERNES" TEXT, "SABADO" TEXT, "DOMINGO" TEXT,
"_ID" NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL )"
```

My Database.class

```
public class MyDataBase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dietas.sqlite";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  public MyDataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  public Cursor getDieta() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String [] sqlSelect = {"INDICACIONES", "LUNES", "MARTES", "MIERCOLES", "JUEVES", "VIERNES", "SABADO", "DOMINGO","_ID"}; 
    String sqlTables = "1_BASICA_1500";

    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
            null, null, null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;

  }
}
```

Class to show the content:

```
public class DietaFragment extends Fragment {
  Bundle paquete;
  TextView txtDieta;
  String nombre;
  MyDataBase db;
  Cursor cursor;

  public DietaFragment(Bundle pack) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    paquete = pack;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dieta, container, false);
    txtDieta = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtDieta);
    db = new MyDataBase(this.getActivity());

    cursor = db.getDieta();

    //nombre = paquete.getString("nombre");

    txtDieta.setText(cursor.getString(0));
    return rootView;
  }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
06-17 12:02:58.933: W/System.err(1630): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
unrecognized token: "1_BASICA_1500" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT INDICACIONES,
LUNES, MARTES, MIERCOLES, JUEVES, VIERNES, SABADO, DOMINGO, _ID FROM 1_BASICA_1500
```

If can help me pls, thanks for watching!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table names cannot begin with a number, unless you use escaping symbols.

Try

```
String sqlTables = "[1_BASICA_1500]";
```

Comment: Thanks I change the name, but now I have other error:  (1) no such table: BASICA1

Comment: @Phantomluffy Are you actually creating the BASICA1 table? Note: to make sure create db runs again, increase DATABASE_VERSION.

Comment: Sorry i am noob in that :(. Now I have other problem

Upgrading database dietas.sqlite from version 1 to 2...
missing database upgrade script: databases/dietas.sqlite_upgrade_1-2.sql
no upgrade script path from 1 to 2
Couldn't open dietas.sqlite for writing (will try read-only):

Comment: Implement onupgrade. The easiest way is to drop all tables and call oncreate.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand you. I am using SQLiteAssetHelper, and I have gotten this information here. 

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper